# How to update youtube video description and add annotation with PHP (and you tube api v2)

Tags: php, youtube

I am trying to do this for last few days, so it is time to ask for some help.

I have about 1.000 videos on you tube in my video channel and I want to use API to change :
1) for each video description
2) to add annotation for each video

I have prepared video description and annotation, but I am not sure, how to access to youtube with PHP. list all video and for each change those data?

Answer (score 1):

Just checked the youtube API myself. This [entry](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_updating_and_deleting_videos) shows you how to update videos on youtube, including description. Also have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authentication) since you'll have to authorize in order to update videos.

You'll need a list of your video id's ([this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php?hl=en-EN#Retrieving_Uploads) might help you with that).

The rest would be building some PHP logic, containing the new descriptions.